# Java's interface + lambda in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda, callback

Given the following snippets of code written in Java, is there a way to elegantly achieve the same result in Python?

Class:

```
public class SomeClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("One");
    list.add("Two");
    list.add("Three");

    goOverList(list.size(), (index) -> list.add(String.valueOf(index + 1)));

    list.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static void goOverList(int listSize, Fun fun) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
      fun.doStuff(i);
    }

  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface Fun {

  void doStuff(int index);

}
```

Output:

```
One
Two
Three
1
2
3
```

The idea is to pass any function as a parameter and get index to work with.

Comment: There is. Why don't you try to write some Python? :)

Comment: Well Python has dynamic typing. So that means you do not need to define interfaces at all. It is *duck typing: If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it is a duck*.

Answer (score 0):

5 lines of Python:

```
the_list = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
for i in range(len(the_list)) :
    the_list.append(str(i + 1))
#end for
print(the_list)
```

Output:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', '1', '2', '3']
```

What do I win?

Comment: The idea was to pass any function as a parameter and get index to work with.

Comment: You mean, like [this](https://github.com/ldo/screencalc_android/blob/master/src/Rules.java) versus [this](https://github.com/ldo/screencalc/blob/master/screencalc)?